# StreamCorruptedException when converting decrypted byte array from socket into class object

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

To sum up the environment: I am building a network library with a class called `Packet`, I'll call it `po` for simplicity. When I receive a packet with my Java Socket, it casts the received data to `po`.

Receiving Method:

```
public Packet ReceiveUnencryptedPacket() throws ReadPacketException {
    Packet p = new Packet(Packet.PACKET_TYPE.NULL, ""); // Packet is my 'po'

    if (!connectionActive)
        return p;

    try {
        // in is ObjectInputStream
        p = (Packet) in.readObject(); // <-- receiving and casting to 'po'
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ReadPacketException(
                "Error reading the received data. Possible causes: Wrong Object Type; Incomplete Send;");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new ReadPacketException(
                "Unable to find class Packet when reading in the data from the socket stream! Fatal Error.");
    }

    return p;
}
```

And Writing Method:

```
public boolean SendUnencryptedPacket(Packet p) throws SendPacketException {
    if (!connectionActive)
        return false;

    try {
        out.writeObject(p); // out is ObjectOutputStream
        out.flush();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new SendPacketException("Error sending packet to socket. PacketType: " + p.packetType.toString()
                + ". PacketMessage: " + p.packetString);
    }
}
```

This works already, no issues have been had.

Now for the fun part. I'm trying to implement an RSA 512 bit Encryption library I built for educational purposes (not for school, just to learn). Without networking, the encryption works for generating keys, accepting keys, encrypting and decrypting objects.

When I implement the encryption to the networking library, it has an issue receiving the `po`'s being sent from either side. For example, I have my handshake. When the server sends it's public key, the client can read it because it's unencrypted. But when the client tries to send it's public key back the server can't convert it into a `po` object to read it. The `po` class has a constructor that will take `byte[]` as a parameter and convert it into a `po` object, and then copy all the values into itself.

Here is `po`'s constructor for that instance:

```
public Packet(byte[] packetBytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Packet p;
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(packetBytes);
    ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
    p = (Packet) in.readObject();
    // data assignment omitted for space-saving. Not the issue
}
```

This constructor functions fine when reading a saved object from a saved file, I don't think it's the issue either.

To be noted, however. The `ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)` is where the exception is being thrown from.

To create the new `po` object, I have this method. It receives a `BigInteger` array from the socket, and processes it.

```
public Packet ReceivePacket() throws ReadPacketException {
    Packet p = new Packet(Packet.PACKET_TYPE.NULL, "");

    if (!connectionActive)
        return p;

    try {
        BigInteger[] encryptedBytes = (BigInteger[]) in.readObject();
        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[encryptedBytes.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < encryptedBytes.length; i++) {
            packetBytes[i] = kript.decrypt(encryptedBytes[i]);
        }

        p = new Packet(packetBytes); // PROBLEM CHILD, PACKET ISN'T ABLE TO
                                        // BE CREATED//

        return p;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // <-- happens any time an encrypted packet is received. Traces back to the declaration in the `po` constructor I mentioned directly above
        throw new ReadPacketException(
                "Error reading the received data. Possible causes: Wrong Object Type; Incomplete Send;");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new ReadPacketException(
                "Unable to find class Packet when reading in the data from the socket stream! Fatal Error.");
    }
}
```

The exception thrown is this:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: DD1E0005
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Netta.Connection.Packet.<init>(Packet.java:80)
at Netta.Connection.Connection.ReceivePacket(Connection.java:189)
at Netta.Connection.Server.ConnectedClient.HandShake(ConnectedClient.java:106)
at Netta.Connection.Server.ConnectedClient.<init>(ConnectedClient.java:40)
at Heart.ClientConnection.<init>(ClientConnection.java:21)
at Heart.Server.ThreadAction(Server.java:27)
at Netta.Connection.Server.MultiClientServer.run(MultiClientServer.java:89)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The stream header mentioned changes every single time it's thrown.

So, my first thought is that the Packet being received by the socket is corrupted or encrypted as well. However I don't think that CAN be the case, seeing as how Sockets handle their own communication and the data being encrypted-decrypted is what's available to me.

Just to be sure, here is the encrypted sending method:

```
public boolean SendPacket(Packet p) throws SendPacketException { // Packet p is my `po` object
    if (!connectionActive)
        return false;

    try {
        byte[] packetBytes = p.ToBytes();
        BigInteger[] encryptedBytes = new BigInteger[packetBytes.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < packetBytes.length; i++) {
            encryptedBytes[i] = kript.encrypt(packetBytes[i]);
        }

        out.writeObject(encryptedBytes);
        out.flush();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new SendPacketException("Error sending packet to socket. PacketType: " + p.packetType.toString()
                + ". PacketMessage: " + p.packetString);
    }
}
```

Why is it that when I send an unencrypted packet, everything works fine, but as soon as it's encrypted it's unable to create the `po` object to read from?

Comment: Pointless without seeing the encrypt/decode code. Does your encryption process work without the serialization part? It all seems very strange. Why would one byte of plaintext produce a `BigInteger`?

Comment: it's RSA 512 bit encryption. It uses the same algorithm off of wikipedia, and generates a 512 bit prime number using BigInteger (because int isn't able to hold such a number). The encryption/decryption takes a byte and BigInteger respectively, and return the opposite. If you want I can show you the result of encrypting 'W', but it's a bit too long for a single comment. I don't feel it's necessary to provide the code however, as the process works perfectly before adding it to networking

Comment: RSA encryption does not produce a prime number. It *uses* prime numbers. How does it go on 0xAC?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. The encryption library generates it's own prime numbers, to use for the RSA keys. 
However I'm not sure as to what you mean by your last question. If I understand correctly, you want me to use 172 as the test prime (which obviously wouldn't work as it's not a prime)?

Comment: I am asking you whether your encryption code can encrypt and decrypt the byte 0xAC correctly, which is the first byte of an `ObjectOutputStream`. The indication at present is that the round-trip produces 0xDD. I'm also not convinced that RSA ciphertext is exactly the same length as the plaintext, although it is certainly possible. Your code above assumes it is.